# AS3. How to set exact y coordinates for game stage ground?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, character, coordinates

I have gravity in game, after game starts character starts falling down. I added ground texture and made collision with that, but for now It "lagging" walking animation when touching the ground. Maybe Is It possible to make It simple by setting game stage's END_y. I mean that for example set y 500 where character stopped falling down?
Thank you for answers.

Comment: For what it's worth if you're programming collision detection in as3 you're reinventing the wheel. I'd look into a game engine like Flixel to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you check that if your character is below the ground to move him above it before the end of your loop.

CORRECT:

```
character.y+=5;
If (character.bottom > ground.top) {
   character.bottom = ground.top;
}
```

INCORRECT:

```
If (character.bottom > ground.top) {
   character.bottom = ground.top;
}
character.y+=5;
```

Or like you said:

```
if (character.y != 500) {
    character.y+=5;
    if (character.y>500) {
        character.y=500;
    }
}
```